# Why is executing Java code unicode not displaying

Tags: java

I try to print the sign language Unicode character to Jframe label. it cannot support. I can do in VB .Net. i am using sign writing 2010 unicode font(https://github.com/Slevinski/signwriting_2010_fonts
). The example unicode is \u1D832

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestUnicode extends JFrame {
  String RUPEE = "\u1D832";

  public TestUnicode() {
   setLayout(new FlowLayout());
   JLabel b = new JLabel("" + RUPEE);
   b.setFont(new Font("SignWriting 2010", Font.PLAIN, 250));
   add(b);
  }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TestUnicode t= new TestUnicode();
        t.setVisible(true);
    t.setSize(300,300);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\u1D832` means `\u1D83` + '2'. Remember Java uses UTF-16 internally.

You can write it as follows, if you want to keep the `1D832` code point value.

```
String RUPEE = new String(Character.toChars(0x1D832));
```

Or you can write it as:

```
String RUPEE = "\uD836\uDC32"; // 1D832
```

Comment: Not display the character